# Update Panel not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a read-only `TextBox` and an Edit button. When I click the button the `textbox` should be readable and the Save button should appear. This happens perfectly, but the whole page is reloading all the time. I have used an `UpdatePanel` but nothing happened. Can someone help me to solve my problem please? Thanks in advance.

**ASPX**:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="edit" eventname="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>

                   <asp:TextBox ID="q" runat="server" ReadOnly style="width:90%" 
                       BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                   <asp:Button ID="edit" class="button3"  style="float:right"  
                       runat="server" Text="Edit" onclick="editqellim_Click"  />
                    <asp:Button ID="save"  class="button3"  style="float:right" runat="server" 
                       Text="Save" onclick="Button1_Click" Visible="False" />
                 </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**code behind**:

```
protected void editqellim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        q.ReadOnly = false;
        q.BackColor = Color.White;
        save.Visible = true;

    }
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a blank solution and got it to work perfectly. What framework version are you running? Do you have other UpdatePanels in your website that ARE working?

Comment: I've have done the same that @Rob using Framework 4 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd bet there's a bad javascript error on the page which is breaking Microsoft's javascript for the UpdatePanel. If you load the page with the developer console showing, do you get any javascript errors immediately on loading? Maybe something that kills javascript on the page? Or any javascript errors as you click the button?

If so, I bet that error is killing the AJAX stuff, leaving the button as a regular submit button, which submits the form like it would without the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Yes thats true,    GET http://localhost:49618/servis/ScriptResource.axd?d=yrxxALadSmpR7w9RWONxT9wI…yGLTvFSpzRagsozXBJzAJILjrFPufjR5T8Cayqz9FbPX4QeApTaQrK0&t=ffffffffb868b5f4 404 (Not Found) prove.aspx:34
Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load. prove.aspx:43
(anonymous function) but i have no other javascript in it

Comment: i copied the project in a new project and now its working just fine. Thnx a lot :)

Comment: Crazy. But this is one of many reasons why I don't like Microsoft's AJAX voodoo (like UpdatePanels and AjaxForms etc.), and prefer using a standard library like jQuery to do my AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

Change `UpdateMode="Conditional"` to `UpdateMode="Always"`

Comment: REMOVE updatemode="Conditional" from updatepanel tag and also remove <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="edit" eventname="Click" />
            </Triggers> tags.